# golang parsing json file

Tags: json, go

I want to parse the following json file and also reference the individual fields.

The json file has some known pattern: The json file is has two group levels. It will have a variable but unknown number of first level groups. Each first level group will have two second level groups: the rule and config groups. Both the rule group and the config group will have unknown number of key:value pairs.

```
{
  { // Comment: first level group
    { // Comment: second level group
      "rule1": "doA"
      "rule2": "doB"
      "rule3": "doC"
      ...
    }
    {
      "config1": "goA"
      "configX": "goB"
      ...
    }
  }
  ...
  {
    {
      "rule100": "doAAA"
      "rule200": "doBBB"
      "rule300": "doCCC"
      ...
    }
    {
      "config100": "goAAA"
      "configX00": "goBBB"
      ...
  }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't look like valid json, shouldn't the root and the first group be arrays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `map`s and `slice`s for those unknown numbers.

```
type FirstGroup struct {
    Rules Rules `json:"rules"`
    Configs Configs `json:"configs"`
}

type Rules map[string]string

type Configs map[string]string
```

https://play.golang.org/p/zCymz62B9K <- The json in this example is a modified version of your's because your's is not really json.

Comment: Very cool! How can I reference the key field in the rules and configs?